# SharedPreferences change set values after apply()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

Variable declaration

```
public String am_PM1, am_PM2;
        
public static final String AM_PM1 = "";
public static final String AM_PM2 = "";
```

I have 2 string values that are being put in sharedPreferences, but after they get put in and applied, the second value in this case `AM_PM2` overwrites `AM_PM1`. If I change the order of execution and put `AM_PM2` before `AM_PM1`, then `AM_PM1` overwrites the first value.

```
Log.d("lol", "Value before 1: " + am_PM1);
Log.d("lol", "Value before 2: " + am_PM2);

editor.putString(AM_PM1, am_PM1);
editor.putString(AM_PM2, am_PM2);

editor.apply();

Log.d("lol", "" + sharedPreferences.getAll());

Log.d("lol", "Value after 1: " + sharedPreferences.getString(AM_PM1, ""));
Log.d("lol", "Value after 2: " + sharedPreferences.getString(AM_PM2, ""));
```

Screenshot of the console output:

[image]

Comment: Pl add declaration for AM_PM1 & AM_PM2. The value of both the key variable must be same.

Comment: Probably you had the same string value for AM_PM1 and AM_PM2

Comment: @Yeray Thank you, sorry for being silly! Working on my first android app.

Comment: @FlasH No problem, we have all been rookies in the android world ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this for the first time, I didn't realize that the actual string value assigned to the variable mattered. So if you encounter such a problem make sure that you are not as silly as me and have actually assigned a string value to the variable.

```
public static final String AM_PM1 = "amPM1";
public static final String AM_PM2 = "amPM2";
```

Comment: As the other answer says, SharedPreferences is a key value based store. 

Meaning your key is the amPM1 and amPM2 in this answer, but previously they were empty strings, so esentially the same key :)

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` use a Key-Value pair to store data. If your keys are the same, it means every time you write a value, you over write the previous one. Thus giving you unexpected values when you try to retrieve them.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Sorry for being a dummy.

Answer (score 0):

AM_PM1 & AM_PM2 are equal. remove `public static final String AM_PM1 = "";` &    `public static final String AM_PM2 = "";`   do this :

```
  editor.edit().putString("AM_PM1", am_PM1).apply();
  editor.edit().putString("AM_PM2", am_PM2).apply();
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Sorry for being a dummy.